# Agregar imagen a una columna de un Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buen dia,

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion para el control de documentos dentro de la empresa, la interfaz que por el momento estoy trabajando es la de usuarios y muestra los usuarios que están conectados a la aplicacion, como se muestra en la siguiente pantalla:

Esta tabla es llenada con datos de SQL Server.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi pregunta es como puedo agregar otra columna e insertar una imagen digamos un pequeño icono de conectado. Y si pudieran apoyarme con otra pequeña duda como puedo hacer para que no aparezca seleccionada la primera celda de la tabla ya intente clearselection y no funciona.**

El código que utilizo para cargar el datagridview es el siguiente:

```
SqlDataAdapter agregar = new SqlDataAdapter("Select  (RTRIM(LTRIM(Nombre))) as Nombre From Usuarios order by nombre asc", cadena);
            agregar.Fill(datos);
            formulario.DataSource = datos;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = formulario;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;


            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

            cadena.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eso es el evento RowDataBound podrias indicarle que muestre la imagen de acuerdo a una condicion, este evento se ejecutara cuando se llene tu gridview. 
Este es un ejemplo de ASP.NET

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" ...
```

```html
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{          
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Image Path";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A tu primer pregunta. Q1 Mi pregunta es como puedo agregar otra columna e insertar una imagen digamos un pequeño icono de conectado.
R
agregar una columna tipo DataGridViewImageColumn, le puedes agregar la ruta de la imagen de Usuario conectao asi:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        Image image = Image.FromFile("Image Path");
        img.Image = image;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(img);
        img.HeaderText = "Image";
        img.Name = "img";
```